# Update not working in mongo db using codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

**This is my controller:**

```
$key['conversation_id']=1;
$update_data['is_read']=0;
$getupdate = $this->Common_model->update_msg($key,$update_data);
```

**This is my model**

```
function update_msg($updatekey, $updatevalue) {
    $result = $this->mongo_db->db->messages->update($updatekey,array('$set'=> $updatevalue));
    return $result;
}
```

**if I try to print the response then I will get the following result**

```
Array ( [updatedExisting] => 1 [n] => 1 [connectionId] => 10 [err] => [ok] => 1 )
```

Comment: I could not update the mongo db.Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

```
    $converstion_id=1;
    $update_data=0;
    $getupdate = $this->Common_model->update_msg($converstion_id,$update_data);
//In Model
    function update_msg($converstion_id, $update_data)
    {
        $result = $this->mongo_db->db->messages->update(array("converstion_id"=>$converstion_id),array('$set'=>array("is_read"=>$update_data)));
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry [Hari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4998427/hariharaprabu-m) here i am trying to update the "conversation id" not "id".But i tried your code with conversation id.but it not accept the mongoId.

But thanks for your response

Comment: In this case remove the new mongo Id that's it!!

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
$key['conversation_id']=1;
$update_data['is_read']=0;
$data_array['$set'] = $update_data;
$result = this->mongo_db->db->messages->update($key, $data_array);
return $result;
```